# Как правильно обратиться к к функции скользящего среднего в pine?

Tags: scripts, tradingview

Как не оформляю код, всё не там где нужно рисует метку, то в начале истории, то на нулевой цене. Как отобразить метку на линии средневзвешенной уже после расчёта индикатора?

```
//@version=5
indicator("line.get_x1",overlay = true)
barsCount=20
Sma(index) =>
    sum = 0.0
    period=14
    for i = index to period - 1
        sum := sum + close[i] / period
    l=label.new(bar_index-index,sum,str.tostring(index),style=label.style_circle)
    sum
if(barstate.islast) Sma(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что я использовал скопировал из документации функцию ta.sma, а она умеет работать только с нулевого индекса.

Поменял вот так:

```
   for i = index to index + 14 - 1
```

Всё заработало